# Anybody configured Coldfusion 8 with Spring-Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I want to run an application[MVC] with models in Spring framework and Data Access layer in Hibernate, View and Controllers in Coldfusion.

Has anybody configured such and application ?

Comment: I suspect someone somewhere has. Do you have an _actual_ question? If you're looking for discussion, you might want to head over to [cf-talk](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/) instead.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone doing this with version 8: Transfer/Reactor (ORM Frameworks) + ColdSpring for IoC/AOP.

Comment: Take a look here for a similar question. We've got it running in CF9 and Railo and I suspect the same approach will work in CF8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256691/need-suggestion-for-running-a-jpa-hibernate-java-project-on-coldfusion-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Palladium](https://github.com/mnimer/palladium), which allows you to use ColdFusion as the view layer, but everything else is controlled by Spring MVC.

Mike Nimer has a [blog post](http://www.mikenimer.com/?p=371) about setting Spring up in ColdFusion.

I wrote a proof of concept with a Spring bean factory wired into FW/1, but it never went beyond the prototyping phase.  I.e. it works, but has not been tested as production worthy.

Comment: I will try with Palladium, I already tried with javaloader but I was not able to connect to Hibernate sucessfully.